# Core Animation not running in View Controller that also contains a Sprite Kit scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, sprite-kit

In my project, there’s a main View Controller with a subview that contains a Sprite Kit scene. The subview (“MySubview”) is implemented like this:

```
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];

    if (self) {
        myScene* scene = [myScene sceneWithSize: CGSizeMake(WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
        [self presentScene: scene];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The main View Controller initialises this subview like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _mySubview = [[MySubview alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
    [self.view addSubview: mySubview];
}
```

All this is good and working so far. But then I try adding Core Animation on an object outside of the Sprite Kit view. I add the following to my main View Controller’s implementation:

```
CAShapeLayer* circleLayer;

- (void) setupCircle {
    CGPathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(CIRCLE_X, CIRCLE_Y, CIRCLE_WIDTH, CIRCLE_HEIGHT), nil);
    circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circleLayer.path = circlePath;
    circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 10;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: circleLayer];
}

- (void) animateCircle {
    CABasicAnimation* circleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    circleAnimation.duration = 4;
    circleAnimation.fromValue = @0;
    circleAnimation.toValue = @1;
    [circleLayer addAnimation: circleAnimation
                       forKey: @"circleAnimation"];
}
```

And then I change my viewDidLoad method to:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _mySubview = [[MySubview alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
    [self.view addSubview: mySubview];
    [self setupCircle];
    [self animateCircle];
}
```

This draws the circle, but does not animate its stroke. When I comment out all the Sprite Kit subview code, it does animate. Is it a problem with threading, run loops, or something else? I’m stuck here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: possibly a problem with how SKView renders its content, it doesn't use Core Animation. You could try to add a custom UIView on top of the SKView that does the CA animation.